# adjust text position according to bar width

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to adjust the bar value text position below each bar top with barwidth/5 offset.

```
text_y -= bar.get_width()/5 # <- not work
```

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects
import math
import numpy as np

def save_fig(fig,pngname):
    fig.savefig(pngname, dpi=fig.dpi, bbox_inches="tight")
    print("[[%s]]"%pngname)    
    return

def plot_bar(df):
    xname = df.columns[0]    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
    x = np.arange(len(df[xname]))
    n = len(df.columns[1:])
    bar_width = 0.95/n
    fontsize = 20

    colors = ['#5891ad','#004561','#ff6f31','#1c7685','#0f45a8','#4cdc8b','#0097a7']
    dy = -bar_width/10
    bars = []
    # add bars
    for i,colname in enumerate(df.columns[1:]):
        bar = ax.bar(x+i*bar_width, df[colname], width=bar_width,color=colors[i])
        bars.append(bar)

    # add text on bars
    for bar in ax.patches:
        bar_value = bar.get_height()
        text = f'{bar_value:,}'
        text_x = bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2
        text_y = bar.get_y() + bar_value
        text_y -= bar.get_width()/5 # <- not work
        bar_color = bar.get_facecolor()
        t = ax.text(text_x, text_y, text, ha='center', va='top', color=bar_color,
              size=fontsize)
        t.set_path_effects([PathEffects.withStroke(linewidth=bar_width*15, foreground='w')])

    ax.set_xticks(x +  1/ 2 - bar_width/2)
    ax.set_xticklabels(df[xname])

    ax.legend()
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    #ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    #ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('#DDDDDD')
    ax.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)
    ax.yaxis.grid(True, color='#EEEEEE')
    ax.xaxis.grid(False)

    ax.set_xlabel('x', labelpad=15)
    ax.set_ylabel('y', labelpad=15)
    ax.set_title('title', pad=15)

    fig.tight_layout()    

    plt.show()
    return

data = [['a',3,2,1],
    ['b',2,3,1],
    ['c',3,1,3],
    ['d',5,1,3],    
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['f1','f2','f3','f4'])
plot_bar(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to have the text? How is this supposed to be related to bar width? What difference would it make since all your bars are the same width? And where are you trying to do that in your code?

Comment: I would like each bar value text below the bar top with barwidth/5 offset. updated.

Comment: The problem is that the data coordinate system is not square, i.e. lengths in x-direction don't map 1:1 to lengths in y-direction. If you really need to have exactly a fifth of the bar width, you can figure out how to do it with Matplotlib's transformations tutorial: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html
but I would just eye-ball it and use `text_y -= 0.2` or something like this.